# Protractor allScriptsTimeout seems not working while loading the application in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, protractor, timeout

My scripts are failing due to timeout as my page some times takes more than 30 secs to load. by browsing online I found few options that could be used but none of them are working correctly. I used getPageTimeout, allScriptsTimeout, defaultTimeoutInterval (in JasminNodeOpts)
 and

```
 beforeEach(function () {
                    originalTimeout = jasmine.defaultTimeoutInterval;
                    jasmine.defaultTimeoutInterval = 50000;
                });
```

None of them are working for me. Every time I get the following error.

```
Failed: Timed out waiting for asynchronous Angular tasks to finish after 11 seconds
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am stuck with this issue.

my conf.js file

```
//conf.js

exports.config = {
  framework: 'jasmine',
  specs: ['./e2e/spec.js'],
  seleniumServerJar: "../bin/selenium-server-standalone-3.9.1.jar",
  chromeDriver: "../bin/chromedriver.exe",
  seleniumPort: 4444,
  resultJsonOutputFile:'./tests/protractorResults.json',
  onPrepare: function () {
    var SpecReporter = require('jasmine-spec-reporter').SpecReporter
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({
      displayStacktrace: 'all'
    }));
  },
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    // getPageTimeout : 100000,
    chromeOptions: {
     args: ['start-maximized','show-fps-counter=true']
    }
  },
    // getPageTimeout: 100000,
    // allScriptsTimeout: 100000,

    jasmineNodeOpts: {
      defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say you used `allScriptsTimeout` and `defaultTimeoutInterval`, you used those within your conf file, and not your spec correct? Also, it would be useful if you were to post your conf file, as that is likely where the issue is

Comment: @BenMohorc, yes I tried those in conf.js file. I tried one after one by commenting each of them. Please find my conf.js code updated

Answer (score 0):

Based on your error, it appears the issue is due to lack of `allScriptsTimeout`. In my conf.js, I have the timeouts setup like:

```
jasmineNodeOpts:{
  defaultTimeoutInterval:150000,
},
allScriptsTimeout: 50000,
```

However, it appears you have tried this unsuccessfully. A way to get around this is to use [browser.wait](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait) with [Expected Conditions](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions). Using `browser.wait()` will use its own timeout that you provide.

Find an element that is only visible after your page is done loading, and do something like:

```
let EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
let loaded = element(by.css('div.finallyLoaded'));  //put element here
let waitTime = 50000;  //in ms
browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(loaded),waitTime);
```

Comment: Actually my system acting weirdly, I just used allScriptsTimeout:60000 and it is working fine now. But still getting an error in one place where after the page is loaded I have to click on Next button to load next page.   I am getting the following error after it loaded the page.   

`Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.`    Not sure whats wrong I am doing here